# Looking for the Name of this property: $\mathsf{P}\left(X \leqslant x\right) = \mathsf{P}\left(h(X) \leqslant h(x)\right)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, terminology

$h(\cdot)$ denotes a strict monotonic increasing transformation such as $\log$.

Another inequality I do not quite get is that

$$\mathsf{P}\left(h(X) \le h(x)\right) \ge \mathsf{P}\left(X \le h(x)\right)$$

Some help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Which property do you want? The one in the title of your question or the one in the text of your question?

Answer (score 3):

No name that I know for the property in the title, which is a simple consequence of the identity, valid for any strictly increasing function $h$,
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega\mid h(X(\omega))\leqslant h(x)\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leqslant x\}.
$$
**Note:** The inequality in the body cannot be true in general.

Comment: hm ok. for the inequality in the body dont we got something like {ω∈Ω∣h(X(ω))<=h(x)}<={ω∈Ω∣X(ω)<=h(x)}? i mean since x <= h(x) is true the quantatiy {ω∈Ω∣X(ω)<=h(x)} has to be larger or equal to {ω∈Ω∣h(X(ω))<=h(x)}?

Comment: Did you try this for the function $h=\log_{10}$ mentioned in your post, and $x=10,000,000$? Then $[\log(X)\lt\log(10,000,000)]=[\log(X)\lt7]=[X\lt10,000,000]$ but you suggest to replace it by $[X\lt7]$...

Comment: oh s*** i turned the <= the wrong way around. it is supposed to be a "=>" instead of "<=". i already edited it. im very sorry about this!

Comment: Still wrong! Try $h(x)=10^x$.

Comment: hm well ok than the statement just does not hold. thx alot!